# oracle error : add primary key

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have this table in my sgbd oracle 11g.

[image]

and this is my request sql:

```
 CREATE TABLE "BMT"."DIM_CLIENT" (
    "ID_DIM_CLIENT" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "NOMCOMPLET_CLT" VARCHAR2(40 BYTE), 
    "ADRESSE_CLT" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "NUM_TEL" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "EMAIL_CLT" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
    "TYPE_CLT" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ;
```

When I add my primary key, I get this error:

> ORA-02437: cannot validate (BMT.DIM_CLIENT_PK) - primary key violated.

Comment: Show us the SQL you use to add the primary key. Your `CREATE TABLE` statement doesn't have one.

Comment: There is duplicate data for whatever column(s) you are trying to create a primary key on.  What were you expecting?

Answer (score 0):

How are you adding the primary key to the table. Please see below, i didnot get any issue when I added it. I hope i understood your query properly or you wanted to achieve something else.

To illustrate what @sstan said, i show you one demo. I hope that would clarify your doubts.

***I created a table without any PK.***

```
CREATE TABLE DIM_CLIENT (
    ID_DIM_CLIENT NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE , 
    NOMCOMPLET_CLT VARCHAR2(40 BYTE), 
    ADRESSE_CLT VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    NUM_TEL VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    EMAIL_CLT VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
    TYPE_CLT VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)
   );
```

***Then i inserted the below set of records:***

```
Insert into DIM_CLIENT (ID_DIM_CLIENT, NOMCOMPLET_CLT, ADRESSE_CLT, NUM_TEL, EMAIL_CLT,  TYPE_CLT)
 Values  (1, 'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD@DDD',   'EEEE');
Insert into DIM_CLIENT (ID_DIM_CLIENT, NOMCOMPLET_CLT, ADRESSE_CLT, NUM_TEL, EMAIL_CLT,  TYPE_CLT)
 Values  (1, 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD', 'EEE@DDD',    'FFF');
Insert into DIM_CLIENT (ID_DIM_CLIENT, NOMCOMPLET_CLT, ADRESSE_CLT, NUM_TEL, EMAIL_CLT,  TYPE_CLT)
 Values  (1, 'CCC', 'DDD', 'EEE', 'FFF@DDD',    'GGG');
COMMIT;
```

If you look above i inserted records to the table with `ID_DIM_CLIENT` as '1' for all the records

***Now i try to add the Primary key to the table:***

```
alter table DIM_CLIENT add primary key (ID_DIM_CLIENT) ;
```

And i get the error:

```
SQL>  alter table DIM_CLIENT add primary key (ID_DIM_CLIENT) ;  
 alter table DIM_CLIENT add primary key (ID_DIM_CLIENT)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02437: cannot validate (T541682.SYS_C001225687) - primary key violated
```

I hope my demo made it clear where is the problem. Its the `ID_DIM_CLIENT` data which is duplicate in your existing table on which you are trying to create the PK. PK doesnot allow any duplicates.

Comment: when I do this: alter table DIM_CLIENT add primary key ID_DIM_CLIENT

Comment: thank you.when i do this request :-                                                    alter table DIM_PRST drop constraint DIM_PRST_PK;
create index IND_DIM_PRST  on DIM_PRST(ID_DIM_PRST);
ALTER TABLE BMT.DIM_PRST  ADD CONSTRAINT DIM_PRST_PK
 PRIMARY KEY  (ID_DIM_PRST) ENABLE NOVALIDATE;     the primary key is added

Comment: Ok..but its not validated. Then wat's the use of creating it, if you are not using it.

Answer (score 0):

Execute this query:

```
SELECT id_dim_client, COUNT(*)
FROM   bmt.dim_client
GROUP  BY id_dim_client
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

If it returns any rows, you cannot add primary key on ID_DIM_CLIENT.